# Outside Box-Shadow for ClipPath HTML Button

Tags: javascript, html, css, overlay, clip-path

At the moment I have a background picture which shows single elements for some menu structure. I started to put some transparent buttons over the image to navigate to single pages depends on which element on the image you click. Then I use `box-shadow: 0 0 0 2000px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);` to make the whole div with the image with some small overlay only the button should be clear. On normal Buttons it works. Now the Problem: I have to use Clip path to match the button to the image elements but Clip Path don't support outside box shadows that's why my background don't shows up the overlay. Is there another option to do this?

When i hover over the button i want that the image has some white overlay but the button should be clear and transparent to see the normal background without the opacity. For normal Buttons it works but i need a solution for button designed with clip-path

```css
#panel {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
}

#homeFontsH1 {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  z-index: 3;
}

#homeFontsH2 {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 2%;
  display: flex;
  z-index: 3;
}

#mainDiv {
  width: 80%;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}

#bg {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#ButtonNotWork {
  position: absolute;
  width: 27.2%;
  top: 25%;
  left: 16.9%;
  rotate: 41deg;
  height: 15%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-style: none;
  z-index: 0;
  //background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
  clip-path: polygon(8% 0%, 0% 41%, 0% 50%, 3.4% 63%, 40% 63%, 33% 100%, 93% 100%, 100% 70%, 98% 50%, 90% 24%, 80% 5%, 80% 5%, 75% 0%);
}

#ButtonNotWork:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2000px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}

#ButtonWorks {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-style: none;
  height: 11.7%;
  width: 3.3%;
  left: 69.1%;
  top: 21%;
  z-index: 0;
}

#ButtonWorks:hover {
  background: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2000px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<div id="panel">
  <div id="mainDiv">
    <img id="bg" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300">
    <button id="ButtonNotWork" title="ButtonNotWork"></button>
    <button id="ButtonWorks" title="ButtonWorks"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre], and then edit your question accordingly. Show the relevant code, instead of just giving a verbal explanation.

Comment: Do you not have any sample code or screenshots to share? That would make it easier to help you. Otherwise, someone may just move on and spend their time helping another post.

Comment: Here some fast created Code because i cannot share the original. The "Button Works" shows the correct overlay in background when you hover. The "ButtonNotWorks" don't create any background

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with `box-shadow`. But you can add a div after the buttons and show it on `:hover` over the buttons. Something like this:

```css
#panel {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
}

#mainDiv {
  width: 80%;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}

#bg {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#ButtonNotWork {
  position: absolute;
  width: 27.2%;
  top: 25%;
  left: 16.9%;
  rotate: 41deg;
  height: 15%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-style: none;
  clip-path: polygon(8% 0%, 0% 41%, 0% 50%, 3.4% 63%, 40% 63%, 33% 100%, 93% 100%, 100% 70%, 98% 50%, 90% 24%, 80% 5%, 80% 5%, 75% 0%);
}

#ButtonWorks {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-style: none;
  height: 11.7%;
  width: 3.3%;
  left: 69.1%;
  top: 21%;
}

.layer {
  position: fixed;
  inset: 0;
  z-index: 660;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

#mainDiv button:hover {
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 666;
}

#mainDiv button:hover ~ .layer {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="panel">
  <div id="mainDiv">
    <img id="bg" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300">
    <button id="ButtonNotWork" title="ButtonNotWork"></button>
    <button id="ButtonWorks" title="ButtonWorks"></button>
     <div class="layer"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

With your permission, I hardly fixed your code, but I strongly suggest that you at least use classes instead of ids in your css.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it does't solve my problem. I want that the button is still transparent by hover to see the background clear. In your solution the buttons get the background from your created layer